# Why is the Row of a named range in Excel not an integer

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub fix_name_ranges()
    Dim rangeData As Range
    Dim startRow As Integer

    Set rangeData = ThisWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersToRange
    Set startRow = rangeData.Row
```

The last statement gives an error of:

```
Compile Error

Object Required
```

rangeData.Row is an object of Integer, no?

Comment: Drop the `Set`. And use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: `rangeData.Row` is a property of the range object.  Since the number of rows in a worksheet is > 32,762, you should declare it as type `Long`.  The `Set` statement assigns an object reference, but since `rangeData.Row` represents a property and not an object, you get the `Object Required` error.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already given the quick solution - remove the `Set` keyword, because this is a value assignment, not a reference assignment.

> *rangeData.Row is an object of Integer, no?*

No. Let's learn how to fish here. Hit F2 to bring up the Object Browser; locate the `Range` class, then its `Row` member:

[image: Object Browser listing the members of 'Range']

`Range.Row` is a read-only `Long` integer property. So yes, it's an *integer* value (`Long` is a 32-bit signed integer type), but not an `Integer` (that's a 16-bit signed integer type), and not an *object* either.

> ```
> Dim startRow As Integer
> ```

Change that declaration to `As Long`, to avoid *overflow* errors when you assign it to anything greater than `2^15-1` (i.e. 32,767).

Intrinsic data types are assigned with what's dubbed a "let" assignment:

```
[Let] startRow = 42
```

Of course that `Let` keyword is deprecated and redundant, you don't need to specify it. But just know that it's implicitly there, whenever you are assigning a *value*.

When you assign an *object reference*, then you need a "set" assignment, like you (correctly) have here:

```
Set rangeData = ThisWorkbook.Names("test_range").RefersToRange
```

The intrinsic data types ("let assignment") are your `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Currency`, `Date`, `Double`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Single`, ..and probably others I'm forgetting; object data types ("set assignment") are `Object`, and any data type defined by a class, like `Range`, `Worksheet`, and `Class1`.

The reason a `Set` keyword is required, is because objects can have a parameterless *default member* that make the assignment ambiguous otherwise:

```
foo = Range("A1")
```

If `Set` wasn't required, VBA wouldn't have a way to know whether `foo` is supposed to hold a `Range` reference, or whether that assignment means to grab the `Range` object's default property value, and assign *that* value to `foo`.